# React. Headless UI Menu Items can't receive focus on keyboard navigation

Tags: reactjs, headless-ui

I have a dropdown menu builth with Headless UI Menu component, but the menu links inside this dropdown are not getting focused on keyboard navigation.

my code goes something like so:

```
function Dropdown(parent, children) {

    return (             
        <Menu as="div" className="Submenu">
            {
                ({close}) => (
                    <>
                        <Menu.Button>
                            { parent.label }
                        </Menu.Button>
                        <Menu.Items as="ul" className="subitems">
                            {
                                children.map(child => (
                                    <Menu.Item as="li" className="subitem" key={ child.id }>
                                        <Link href={ child.link }>
                                            {  child.label }
                                        </Link>                                    
                                    </Menu.Item>
                                ))
                            }
                        </Menu.Items>                    
                    </>
                )
            }
        </Menu>
    );
}
```

The only thing getting the focus is the `<ul></ul` that wraps the items, but once I press tab the dropdown closes and the focus goes to the next item on the parent level menu.

[image]

The final html rendered is this:

[image]

I've tried to add `tabIndex={0}` to the  tags, but the output stays the same.
I also tried to create a Link wrapper component ike suggested [here](https://headlessui.com/react/menu#integrating-with-next-js), but it didn't work.

Comment: What about `tabIndex={i}` on `<Menu.Item>`? [A negative value means that the element is not reachable via sequential keyboard navigation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex).

Comment: I've added it, but it doesn't change the html output. `<Menu.Item as="li"  tabIndex={0}>` or any number has no effect, the output html always render with tabindex=-"1"

Answer (score 0):

The main focus should stay on `ul` element, it's okay. But there is an internal focus that you can change using arrows, it's just now showing. You can test it by navigating using arrows and pressing enter. Links will work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have the same problem as the OP, and arrows don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the popover. I ran into the same trouble with the menu, and the popover let's you tab into it.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this issue, I found that it happens if you use the `as` prop of Menu.Item. Removing that causes it to render a fragment and then the ref is passed properly. On this note, the child component of Menu.Item also must accept a ref, either by being a primitive element (i.e. button) or by using a custom component that forwards a ref to a primitive.